# Vue3: Two-way binding with two child components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have three components `Table.vue` -> `Filters.vue` -> `Selectbox.vue`. Table.vue contains a reactive variable `options`

**Table.vue**

```
<script setup>
    import { reactive } from 'vue';
    import Filters from './Filters';

    defineProps({
        per_page_options: { type: Array, required: false },
    });

    const options = reactive({
        per_page: 10,
        current_page: 1,
    });
</script>

<template>
    <Filters :per_page="options.per_page" :per_page_options="per_page_options" />
</template>
```

Filters.vue is used to pass down the properties to different filters (To make it simple, I only show the code to a dropdown component)

**Filters.vue**

```
<script setup>
    import { ref } from 'vue';

    const props = defineProps({
        per_page: { type: Number, required: false },
        per_page_options: { type: Array, required: false, default: () => [10, 20, 50] },
    });

    const results_per_page = ref(props.per_page || props.per_page_options[0]);
</script>

<template>
    <Selectbox :label="$t('result_per_page', 1)" :options="per_page_options" id="results_per_page" v-model="results_per_page" horizontal small />
</template>
```

The `per_page` prop can't be linked to v-model due mutation so I created an extra ref but that breaks the binding between the `Table` and `Filters` component. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use v-model, but then you have to follow the naming pattern:
https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-custom-events.html#handling-v-model-modifiers

The other option would be to have a custom emit which in your Table.vue modifies the per_page option as here it is a reactive and can be modified.

Comment: If I use the v-model in `Table.vue` for the Filters component like this `<Filters v-model:per_page="options.per_page" :per_page_options="per_page_options" />` per_page is still a prop inside `Filters` and can't be linked to a v-model on the `Selectbox` component due prop mutation

Comment: @Thore Yes you can. You need to read the full example in the link given. So in order to update the prop when using v-model approach you need to perform an emit with update:perPage `@input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)">`